# Django: pictures not loading in HTML templates

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I add a random picture inside an HTML it doesn't load at all. 
Here is how I set up my Django Project: 
[image]

Inside of index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<img src='{% static "img/logo2.png" %}'>
```

inside of Production, base and local.py I have this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/')
```

Thank you in advance if you can help me.

Comment: But you specify it as the root of the settings file. So right now it should probably be placed in `blankapp/settings/static`. Print the `STATIC_ROOT`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Configuration

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

In your server try to access http://localhost:8000/static/img/logo2.png and check if the image is propely loaded, if the image loads so your confugiration at settings.py is right.

**EDIT:** You using heroku? im not sure if you will e able to use your static files with django at heroku, probabily use some external static server as Amazon S3

Answer (score 1):

Here static folder was inside myapp but you have given root

```
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/')
```

place the static folder into settings of blankapp

change the img src in HTML

check now

Comment: You dont need to use collectstatic in development environment, this is when you have external server to process your statics, so you send all your statics to there... like Amazon S3

Comment: Whitenoise you run one external server inside your django project to handle your statis, this might work for you

Comment: keep in mind the heroku do not work with Media files (if you have any ImageField or FileField in your models) that will not work well on heroku, because everytime you submit a new push, they restart the entire code.... so all your media files is deleted, at least on free version.

Comment: Somehow my collectstatic on Free Tier of Heroku dont works well... so i disable that and run it manually after adding new file... i like to use django-fabric to setup one script with everything that i need to run after new push... like collectstatic, collectmedia (external script to do same thing that collectstatic do but with media), migrate and any base fixture to initiate the static data